Induced emf and coil winding direction
Recently, I've learned that induced emf is there to oppose the change in magnetic flux.
consider a current increasing over time ($\frac{di}{dt}>0)$, moving left to right as it passes through the coil.
First, I am very clear that the winding direction changes polarity of magnetic field. However, I don't really understand why the polarity of induced emf is not affected by the winding direction.
I read an explanation using following equation $\varepsilon=-L\frac{di}{dt}$, saying that the rate of change of current is the only factor that determines the polarity not the winding direction.
Yet there's another equation, $\varepsilon=-N\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$. according to this equation, the sign of magnetic flux depends on winding direction because magnetic field of a clockwise lies with area vector, but for the counter-clockwise it lies with opposite direction. Therefore, winding direction of a coil should affect the polarity of induced emf. - is my thought process so far.
Can anyone find and fix my misconception here? I need a clear explanation of this. Thank you very much.


If $\Phi_B$ denotes flux due to the coil only, then $\Phi_B = LI$, and the formulae give the same result for self-induced emf. Only if $\Phi_B$ denotes flux due to external source of magnetic field, the second formula with it gives different thing - it gives external emf, not self-induced emf.


Suppose a coil with a clockwise winding, perpendicular to the ground.

Let's have a constant current flowing with direction downward. The magnetic field inside the coil, according to the right hand rule, has direction downward. If the current (and the magnetic field) increases, the induction current (it is a way to refer to the induced emf) follow the left hand rule (that is the meaning of the minus sign in the Maxwell-Faraday equation). So it flows upward, opposing the increasing of the current.
Now suppose that we make the initial current decrease instead. Now the downward magnetic field decreases, what is the same to say that it increases upward. According to the left hand rule, the induction current flows downward, opposing the decrease of the current.

Suppose a coil with a counter-clockwise winding, perpendicular to the ground.

Let's have a constant current flowing with direction downward. The magnetic field inside the coil, according to the right hand rule, has direction upward. If the current (and the magnetic field) increases, the induction current follow the left hand rule, and flows upward, opposing the increasing of the current.
Now suppose that we make the initial current decrease instead. Now the upward magnetic field decreases, what is the same to say that it increases downward. According to the left hand rule, the induction current flows downward, opposing the decrease of the current.
